# Why does a DIV not expand to include the "top" values of its children?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very simple web page:

```
<body>
<h1> Welcome to storyblocks alpha</h1>
<div id="blockport"></div>
</body>
```

I have some javascript which adds a child DIV and a few child elements:

```
function testDisplay() {
    alert("This script will run.");
    let box = document.getElementById("blockport")
    console.log(box);
    let node=document.createElement("div");
    node.style.backgroundColor="red";
    box.prepend(node);
    node.className="primitive";
    let header = document.createElement("h")
    header.innerHTML = "This is a header!"
    header.style.position="relative";
    header.style.top="100px";
    node.prepend(header);
    let header2 = document.createElement("h")
    header2.style.position="relative";
    header2.style.top="100px";
    header2.innerHTML = "Testing 1 2 3 ";
    node.append(document.createElement("br"));
    node.appendChild(header2);
```

And the CSS class referred to is:

```
.primitive {
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: inset;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: grab;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

The problem I have comes from these two lines of code:

```
header.style.top="100px";
...
header2.style.top="100px";
```

Without them the display looks like this:
[image]

However, when the those lines are included, it looks like this:

[image]

This problem persists through various changes, such as `position: relative` in `.primitive', among others.

How can I make the `node` element with the red background expand to cover changes to "top" of it's children?  If I try the `.marginTop` or `.paddingTop` property, it seems to have no effect on the final display (although `.margin` will make the div wider.)

I can actually write some javascript that chooses the size of the `let node = ...` element, but this is complicated and seems to violate the KISS (keep it simple, stupid) principle if the browsers will do this for me.

---

How can I make the div expand downwards automatically?  Or do I simply need to compute the height of the `node` element in javascript?

Comment: Positioned elements are taken out of the flow. Therefore, the parent container does not expand to contain the positioned element. Perhaps you could achieve the desired effect with margin or padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `style.display = "block"` and removed `style.position` and used `marginTop` instead of `top`.

Try this:

```js
function testDisplay() {
  alert("This script will run.");
  let box = document.getElementById("blockport")
  console.log(box);
  let node = document.createElement("div");
  node.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  box.prepend(node);
  node.className = "primitive";
  let header = document.createElement("h")
  header.innerHTML = "This is a header!"
  header.style.display = "block";
  header.style.marginTop = "100px";
  node.prepend(header);
  let header2 = document.createElement("h")
  header2.style.display = "block";
  header2.style.marginTop = "100px";
  header2.innerHTML = "Testing 1 2 3 ";
  node.append(document.createElement("br"));
  node.appendChild(header2);
}
testDisplay()
```

```css
.primitive {
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: inset;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: grab;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> Welcome to storyblocks alpha</h1>
  <div id="blockport"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Woah, cool!  So does the "display" property actually communicate with the objects that CONTAIN an object, rather than object that ARE CONTAINED by the object?